# What prerequisites / requirements are needed to have "Mathematical Sophistication"?

Tags: logic, education, proof-theory

Certain courses use this term as a prerequisite, but the term is vague.  Should I assume the term generally means having an understanding of logic and proofs?

Comment: Logic and proofs for sure, but the term "mathematical sophistication" is really context dependent. Best advice is to browse the early chapters of the text (or some text corresponding to the course) to get a sense of the level.

Comment: You should email the professor and ask.  I'd imagine that it's a bit context dependent, but that you have the right idea.  We could probably guess what they mean if you tell us what the class is.

Comment: I have sometimes heard it claimed that it is the ability to write a lowercase zeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this means that you will have developed your skills in not only proof-writing, but also proof-reading$^\dagger$. Moreover, depending on the level of the course, this means that you will be able to fill in omitted bits of reasoning on your own.

$\dagger$ In particular, you should be able to actually extract the reasoning behind the construction of a well-written proof, rather than simply the steps.